# Authorisation through url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization

Say, I have a posts app. There's a form where anyone can fill in fields like title,text,email and subm button. No registration required.

After form submission the post should be moderated. If it's approved then it appears in main list.

**After form submission and approval, user receives a link(link is sent to user's email) for editing their post.** -- how to do this?

**UPD**

The question is not how to moderate or validate a post/usr **but how to give him a link for editing only his post**

Answer (score 3):

Whenever a User record is created you can easily generate a token which is bound to the record like so:

in User.rb

```
before_save :generate_token

def generate_token
  self.token = SecureRandom.hex(6)
end
```

then when submitting the user a registration confirmation link you could do it like so:

```
link_to "Validate account", validate_user_path(token: user.token)
```

and an example of your UsersController

```
def validate
  user = User.find_by_token(params[:token])
  if user
    user.update_attributes(validated: true)
    flash[:notice] = 'User succesfully validated.'
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Couldn't find user with token'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

1. Generate a unique token (e.q. with `SecureRandom.hex`) when the post is saved and send the token to the user.
2. Add a new route to your app. When the user request that URL with the token (`/posts/verify/:token`), let the controller look for a post with a matching token. When found, set a `verified` boolean on the post to `true`.